# Matlab script - how to access from/run in GRASS GIS?

Tags: python, grass-gis, matlab

I am currently working on shell script in GRASS GIS and Ubuntu. At some point, I must run a calculation (based on an ascii grid) that I have available as Matlab script and .exe (created from Matlab I believe). 
For that I must exit GRASS (and boot into Windows), but it would be neat if I could somehow run this from inside GRASS GIS (or at least stay inside Ubuntu). For the non-Matlab and Python-expert...what would be a sensible approach? From what I have understood, converting to Python might be the only real option.

Comment: Please edit the thread title. It should be a question which indicates what the thread is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two solutions, which seem to work:

1) copy the Octave script/function you want to run into the folder accessed by GRASS GIS. Call it with octave --silent --eval [...] as you would in shell. A simple example: my function is "add.m", and looks like:

```
function c = add (a,b) 
c = a+b;`
```

In the command console in GRASS I run octave --silent --eval add(a=5,b=6). The output is ans=11.

2) write an executable. it must have a header in the form "#! /usr/bin/octave -qf"

For example: I create a text file with the name add and the text:

```
#! /usr/bin/octave -qf
a=5;
b=6;
c=add (a,b)
```

In the terminal (converts it into an executable): $ chmod 755 add
In the GRASS console run: ./add 
Output: c=11.

I have not yet done this with more complex scripts and import/export into/from GRASS GIS and Octave (e.g. ascii files), but it should work with this approach.

(Python is probably a more powerful way, but I am accustomed to shell)

Answer (score 3):

1) If you want to run the script from inside GRASS GIS, it is relatively easy to transform the original  Matlab script (.m)  in a Python script if it do not uses specific toolboxes (with [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) and the others scientific Python modules)

2) if you want to run the .m script outside GRASS GIS, you can use [Octave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Octave), open source alternative to run m-code ([MATLAB Programming/Differences between Octave and MATLAB](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Differences_between_Octave_and_MATLAB)) or [FreeMat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeMat) or [SciLab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scilab) (other alternatives)

3) but you can also look if GRASS GIS cannot do directly your processing.

Comment: See also http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Octave (which should be expanded)

Comment: Thank you gene - I will look into either the Python or Octave option. Also thank you markus, for the Link.